# How to loop through item card checkboxes with same id? (Javacsript/ JQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, loops

Good day everyone, I am not sure how can I loop through multiple item cards with 2 checkboxes of the same ID (within each card). There are multiple cards being rendered at the same time.

Currently my main issue is that whenever my code meets a specific condition, it only renders the first item card checkboxes as the id points to it.

I need the checkboxes to render accordingly to the key value pairs that are uniquely stored in the local storage. I am not sure how I can loop through this? Can somebody help me on this? Thank you :)

Html Code:

```
      <form class="g-item-title" style="color: #005e95">
        <input type="radio" id="checkboxPartialDownload" data-dojo-attach-event="onClick: _test" style="cursor: pointer;" name="downloadValue" value="partialDownload" class="classPartialDownload" checked>
        Allow Partial Download
        <br>
        <input type="radio" id="checkboxFullDownload" data-dojo-attach-event="onClick: _onclickTest" style="cursor: pointer;" name="downloadValue" value="fullDownload" class="classFullDownload">
        Allow Partial + Full Download
      </form>
```

JS Code that renders when page loads:

```
      render: function (hit) {
 
        let dataTitle = hit.sort[0];
        let dataid = hit._source.fileid;

        $("input[type='radio'][name='downloadValue']:checked").each(function(){

          if(localStorage.getItem(`${dataTitle}`) === "FullDownload"){
            var value=$(this).attr('value');
           
            if(value ==='partialDownload'){
             $('#checkboxPartialDownload').prop('checked', false); //Only renders the first item checkboxes.. 
             $('#checkboxFullDownload').prop('checked', true);
            }
           }
        })
```

On click function that saves the key value pair to local storage:

```
    _onclickTest:function(evt){
        let title = this.item.title;
        let fileid = this.item.fileid
        localStorage.setItem(`${title}`,'FullDownload')
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the understanding from the question, we need at least one id at the card level for the differentiation purpose. Here we are storing the value in local storage base on the card id. Please refer the code.

```js
$( document).ready(function() {
    $(".g-item-title").each(function(index, element){
      const cardId = $(element).attr("id");
      if(localStorage.getItem(cardId) === "fullDownload"){
        $(element).find(".classFullDownload").prop('checked', true);
      }
    });
});

$(".g-item-title").on("click", ".classFullDownload", function(event){
     const cardId = $(event.target).closest(".g-item-title").attr("id");
     const checkedVal = $(event.target).val();         
     localStorage.setItem(cardId, checkedVal);
});

$(".g-item-title").on("click", ".classPartialDownload", function(event){
     const cardId = $(event.target).closest(".g-item-title").attr("id");
     const checkedVal = $(event.target).val();
     localStorage.removeItem(cardId);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <form class="g-item-title" style="color: #005e95" id="card1">
        <input type="radio" 
               id="checkboxPartialDownload" 
               data-dojo-attach-event="onClick: _test" 
               style="cursor: pointer;" 
               name="downloadValue" 
               value="partialDownload" 
               class="classPartialDownload" checked>
        Allow Partial Download
        <br>
        <input type="radio" 
               id="checkboxFullDownload" 
               style="cursor: pointer;" 
               name="downloadValue" 
               value="fullDownload" 
               class="classFullDownload">
        Allow Partial + Full Download
      </form>
  
  <form class="g-item-title" style="color: #005e95" id="card2">
        <input type="radio" 
               id="checkboxPartialDownload" 
               data-dojo-attach-event="onClick: _test" 
               style="cursor: pointer;" 
               name="downloadValue" 
               value="partialDownload" 
               class="classPartialDownload" checked>
        Allow Partial Download
        <br>
        <input type="radio" 
               id="checkboxFullDownload" 
               style="cursor: pointer;" 
               name="downloadValue" 
               value="fullDownload" 
               class="classFullDownload">
        Allow Partial + Full Download
      </form>
</body>
  
</html>
```